Topographic correction
I am trying to code the topographic correction and I get this error:

"Image (Error) Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required."

I have seen a similar script for an entire collection, but I only need for some specific images.  Here is the code that I have written.
 var ROI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-0.5847357897591099,34.62535230488014,0.4699517102408901,34.103899902)
Map.addLayer(ROI)
var YearList = ee.List.sequence(1984,2023,1) ;  

// Set Biseasonal periods start and end (only images within these periods will be considered for mosaicing)
var StartEarlySummer_Month = 5;
var StartEarlySummer_Day = 1;
var EndEarlySummer_Month = 8;
var EndEarlySummer_Day = 30;
var StartLateSummer_Month = 8;
var StartLateSummer_Day = 15;
var EndLateSummer_Month = 11;
var EndLateSummer_Day = 1;

// Edit cloud threshold to select images (only images under threshold will be kept)
var CloudThreshold = 25;

// Cloud Mask dilation in pixels to include edges
// (default: 240m = 8px - see https://labo.obs-mip.fr/multitemp/issues-with-mdpi-remote-sensing-recent-papers-on-cloud-detection/)
var CloudMaskDilation_px = 8;

// Slope ranges (i.e.list of upper and lower slope values) for slope-dependant SCS+C Topographic correction
// (script section inspired by the work of Patrick Burns and Matt Macander - https://mygeoblog.com/2018/10/17/terrain-correction-in-gee/)
var slopeValues = ee.List.sequence(0, 80, 5); // from 0° to 80° with 5° indentation

// Default: Mosaic as median - see lines 73 and 77 to modify.
// .median() can be replaced by .mean(), .min(), .max(), etc.

// --------------------------------------------------------
// MAIN CODE

// Export (loops through Img_Collection)
var NbYears = YearList.size().getInfo(); // Gets the nmber of years to loop through
  for (var i = 0; i < NbYears; i++) {
    var Year = YearList.get(i).getInfo();  // Get the year value
   
  // Compute Dates to get landsat data
  var StartEarlySummer = ee.Date.fromYMD(Year, StartEarlySummer_Month, StartEarlySummer_Day);
  var EndEarlySummer = ee.Date.fromYMD(Year, EndEarlySummer_Month, EndEarlySummer_Day);
  var StartLateSummer = ee.Date.fromYMD(Year, StartLateSummer_Month, StartLateSummer_Day);
  var EndLateSummer = ee.Date.fromYMD(Year, EndLateSummer_Month, EndLateSummer_Day);
  
  // Step A - Load Landsat Data for both periods, apply Cloud and Saturation, merge both Landsat OLI temperature bands into a single one 
  var ImgCol_ES =  LoadLandSatTM(ROI, CloudThreshold, Year, StartEarlySummer, EndEarlySummer)
                    .merge(LoadLandSatOLI(ROI, CloudThreshold, Year, StartEarlySummer, EndEarlySummer));
  var ImgCol_LS = LoadLandSatTM(ROI, CloudThreshold, Year, StartLateSummer, EndLateSummer)
                    .merge(LoadLandSatOLI(ROI, CloudThreshold, Year, StartLateSummer, EndLateSummer));
                    
  // Apply BRDF correction
  ImgCol_ES = ImgCol_ES.map(BRDFcorrection);
  ImgCol_LS = ImgCol_LS.map(BRDFcorrection);
  
  // Apply Topographic Correction
  ImgCol_ES = ImgCol_ES.map(GetilluminationCondition)
                        .map(ApplyTopographicCorrection);
  ImgCol_LS = ImgCol_LS.map(GetilluminationCondition)
                        .map(ApplyTopographicCorrection);
  
  // Mosaic images collections into single yearly images (median) and rename bands
  ImgCol_ES = ImgCol_ES.median()
                .select(['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2'],  // rename
                                ['lst1_blue_ES', 'lst2_green_ES', 'lst3_red_ES', 'lst4_nir_ES', 'lst5_swir1_ES', 'lst6_swir2_ES']);
  
  ImgCol_LS = ImgCol_LS.median()
                .select(['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2'],  // rename
                                ['lst1_blue_LS', 'lst2_green_LS', 'lst3_red_LS', 'lst4_nir_LS', 'lst5_swir1_LS', 'lst6_swir2_LS']);
  
  // Merge both collections and turns into a single image
  var BiAnnual_ImgCol = ee.ImageCollection(ImgCol_ES).merge(ee.ImageCollection(ImgCol_LS));
   

  // ImageCollections to Image and rename bands
  var BiAnnual_Img = BiAnnual_ImgCol.toBands().set("Year",Year).rename(ImgCol_ES.bandNames().add(ImgCol_LS.bandNames()).flatten());
 
  // Export Image
  Export.image.toAsset({
    image: BiAnnual_Img.int16(), // Convert to Integer
    description: ''+Year+'_composite',
    assetId: 'Landsat_'+Year+'_composite',
    scale: 30,
    region:  ROI,
    maxPixels: 1E10,
    pyramidingPolicy: {
    '.default': 'sample'
  }}); 
}
//-Map.addLayer(BiAnnual_Img.set("Year",2009),{},"Layer1")
 print(BiAnnual_Img,"BiAnnual_ImgCSSol")

//------------------------------------------------
// MAIN FUNCTIONS

// A - load LandSat TM & OLI Data
// NOTE: The two OLI thermal bands are meaned into a single one for comparability with Landsat TM. This step can be removed by commenting it out (line 123).
function LoadLandSatTM(ROI, CloudThreshold, Year, StartDate, EndDate){
    return ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT04/C02/T1_L2")     // Landsat 4 TM
                            .merge(ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2"))    // Landsat 5 TM
                            .filterBounds(ROI)            // Only keep images intersecting the ROI
                            .filterDate(StartDate, EndDate)     // Filters to keep ony relevant period
                            .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', CloudThreshold) // Only keep cloud-free-images
                            //.map(CloudMaskLandsat)                                // Apply cloud mask
                            //.map(SaturationMaskLandsat)                         // Apply pixel saturation mask
              .select(      // Select and rename relevant bands
                            ['SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B7'],
                            ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2'])
                            ;   
}
function LoadLandSatOLI(ROI, CloudThreshold, Year, StartDate, EndDate){
    return ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2") // Landsat 8 OLI
              .filterBounds(ROI)        // Only keep images intersecting the ROI
                            .filterDate(StartDate, EndDate)     // Filters to keep ony relevant period
                            .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', CloudThreshold) // Only keep cloud-free-images
                            //.map(MeanTemperature)// means the two thermal bands to be consistent with Landsat TM
                            //.map(applyScaleFactors)
                            //.map(CloudMaskLandsat)                                // Apply cloud mask
              //.map(SaturationMaskLandsat)                         // Apply pixel saturation mask
              .select(                                // Select and rename relevant bands
                            ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7'],
                            ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2'])
                            ;
}

// B - Bidirectional Reflectance Distribution Function (BRDF) correction for seamless scenes
function BRDFcorrection(image){
  // Compute image footprints
    var footprint = ee.List(image.geometry().bounds().bounds().coordinates().get(0));
    // Compute sun angles from image metadata (date and hour)
    var SunAngles =  GetSunAngles(image, footprint);
    var sunAz = SunAngles[0];
    var sunZen = SunAngles[1];
    // Computes view angles from image footprint
    var viewAz = ViewAzimuth(footprint);
    var viewZen = ViewZenith(footprint);
  // Compute k values
    var kvalues = kvolCalc(sunAz, sunZen, viewAz, viewZen);
    var kvol = kvalues[0];
    var kvol0 = kvalues[1];
return BRDFcorr(image, kvol.multiply(Math.PI), kvol0.multiply(Math.PI));
}

// C - Calculate Illumination Conditions and add bands to image (for later Topographic correction)
function GetilluminationCondition(img){
  // Get image extent
    var extent = img.geometry().bounds();
    // Extract image metadata about solar position
    var SZ_rad = radians(ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(img.get('SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE')))).clip(extent); 
    var SA_rad = radians(ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(img.get('SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE')))).clip(extent); 
    // Create terrain layers
    var dem = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003").clip(extent);
    
    // OPTIONAL - SMOOTH DEM (convolve a low-pass kernel for smoothing)
    //var dem_smoothed = dem.convolve(ee.Kernel.square({radius: 1, units: 'pixels', normalize: true}));
    //var slp = ee.Terrain.slope(dem_smoothed).clip(extent);  // select one or the other if using smoothed dem or not
    var slp = ee.Terrain.slope(dem).clip(extent);         // select one or the other if using smoothed dem or not
    
    var slp_rad = radians(slp).clip(extent);
    var asp_rad = radians(ee.Terrain.aspect(dem)).clip(extent);
    // slope part of the illumination condition (cosZ * cosS)
    var cosZ = SZ_rad.cos();
    var cosS = slp_rad.cos();
    var slope_illumination = SZ_rad.cos().multiply(cosS);
    // aspect part of the illumination condition (sinZ * sinS * cosAziDiff)
    var sinZ = SZ_rad.sin(); 
    var sinS = slp_rad.sin();
    var cosAziDiff = (SA_rad.subtract(asp_rad)).cos();
    var aspect_illumination = cosAziDiff.multiply(sinZ).multiply(sinS);
    // full illumination condition (IC) ((cosZ * cosS) + sinZ * sinS * cosAziDiff))
    var ic = slope_illumination.add(aspect_illumination);
  
  // Mask low or negative illumination condition (topographic shadow)
  var low_ic_mask = ic.gte(0); // only keep positive illumination conditions

// Return image with appended bands of illumination condition and other relevant bands for SCSc correction
return img.addBands(ic.rename('IC'))
          .addBands(cosZ.rename('cosZ'))
          .addBands(cosS.rename('cosS'))
          .addBands(slp.rename('slope'))
          .updateMask(low_ic_mask); // mask low illumination condition pixels
}

// D - Apply slope-range dependant SCSc correction to each band based on scene illumination condition and slope ranges
function ApplyTopographicCorrection(img){
    // Specify Bands to topographically correct  (all but temporary illumination bands)
    var bandList = (img.bandNames()).removeAll(ee.List(['IC', 'cosZ', 'cosS', 'slope']).flatten());
    // Get slope ranges based on user-defined slope values
  var slopeRanges = slopeValues.slice(-0, -1);  // list of all values but the last one
    
    // do topographic correction by looping through all bands to proceed (in the list)
    var img_SCSccorrected = ee.Image(bandList.map(function(bandname){
      // Loops through slope ranges to calculate SCSc corr multiplicators
      var band_SCScorrFactors = ee.List(slopeRanges).map(function(slp){      // slp = slope threshold value
            // get lower and upper limits of slope range
            var lower = ee.Number(slp);
            var upper = ee.Number(slopeValues.get(slopeRanges.indexOf(slp).add(1))); // next on list
            // only retain pixels within that sloperange
            var slope = img.select('slope');
            var slopemask = (slope.gt(lower)).and(slope.lte(upper));
            var img_masked = ee.Image(img).updateMask(slopemask);
            
            // Calcuate band-specific C parameter for the current slope class and compute multiplicator
            var linreg = img_masked.select(['IC', ee.String(bandname)]).reduceRegion({ // Compute coefficients: a(slope), b(offset), c(b/a)
                                    reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(), 
                                    geometry: ROI, 
                                    scale: 30,
                                    maxPixels: 20e9,
                                    //tileScale: 8,
                                    bestEffort: true
                                    });
            // Check linear regression results and computes multiplicator
            var multiplicator = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(linreg.get('offset')),
                    img_masked.expression("(cosS * cosZ + C) / (IC + C)", {
                    'IC':     img_masked.select('IC'),    'cosS': img_masked.select('cosS'),
                    'cosZ':   img_masked.select('cosZ'),  'C':    (ee.Number(linreg.get('offset')).divide(ee.Number(linreg.get('scale'))))}
                    ),
                    ee.Image(1));

      return ee.Image(multiplicator).mask(slopemask).unmask(1).rename('multiplicator');
      });
    
    // Reduce the slope-range specific correction factors to a single image by product
    var Final_band_multiplier = ee.ImageCollection(band_SCScorrFactors).product();
    
    // Apply multiplicator to band
    var BandTopoCorrected = img.select(ee.String(bandname)).multiply(Final_band_multiplier);
    
  return  BandTopoCorrected; // correct the band
  })); 
  // Convert results of corrected images back to a single Image with original band names
  var Corrected_img = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(img_SCSccorrected).flatten()).toBands().rename(bandList);
return ee.Image(Corrected_img);
}


//------------------------------------------------
// Helper Functions
// A.1 - Cloud masking algorithms (based on 'pixel_qa' band, result of CFMASK algorithm)
function CloudMaskLandsat(img){
    // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
    var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
    // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = img.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
        .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  var eroded_mask = mask.focal_min((CloudMaskDilation_px,'circle','pixels',1))  // erodes the mask by n pixel(s) to include cloud borders
return img.updateMask(eroded_mask);
}
// A.2 - Band Saturation masking algorithm (based on 'radsat_qa' band)
function SaturationMaskLandsat(img){
  // Get the radsat QA band.
  var qa = img.select('radsat_qa');
  // All flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.eq(0);
return img.updateMask(mask);
}
// A.3 - Means thermal bands 1 and two in LandSat 8 to only give one thermal bands comparable with Landsat TM
function MeanTemperature(img){
    var meanTemp = ((img.select('SR_B10')).add(img.select('SR_B11'))).divide(2).rename('thermal');
return img.addBands(meanTemp.toShort());
}
// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}

// B.1 - Calulate Sun Angle based on day of year
function GetSunAngles(image, footprint){ // Get sun angles based on image metadata
    var date = image.date();
    var jdp = date.getFraction('year');
    var hourGMT = ee.Number(date.getRelative('second', 'day')).divide(3600); // 3600 seconds in an hour
    
    var latRad = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('latitude').multiply(Math.PI).divide(180);
    var longDeg = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('longitude');
    
    // Julian day proportion in radians
    var jdpr = jdp.multiply(Math.PI).multiply(2);
    
    var a = ee.List([0.000075, 0.001868, 0.032077, 0.014615, 0.040849]);
    var meanSolarTime = longDeg.divide(15.0).add(ee.Number(hourGMT));
    var localSolarDiff1 = value(a, 0)
            .add(value(a, 1).multiply(jdpr.cos())) 
            .subtract(value(a, 2).multiply(jdpr.sin())) 
            .subtract(value(a, 3).multiply(jdpr.multiply(2).cos())) 
            .subtract(value(a, 4).multiply(jdpr.multiply(2).sin()));
  
    var localSolarDiff2 = localSolarDiff1.multiply(12 * 60);
  
    var localSolarDiff = localSolarDiff2.divide(Math.PI);
    var trueSolarTime = meanSolarTime 
            .add(localSolarDiff.divide(60)) 
            .subtract(12.0);
    
    // Hour as an angle;
    var ah = trueSolarTime.multiply(ee.Number(7.5 * 2) // Max Satellite Zenith = 7.5
                            .multiply(Math.PI).divide(180)) ;   
    var b = ee.List([0.006918, 0.399912, 0.070257, 0.006758, 0.000907, 0.002697, 0.001480]);
    var delta = value(b, 0) 
          .subtract(value(b, 1).multiply(jdpr.cos())) 
          .add(value(b, 2).multiply(jdpr.sin())) 
          .subtract(value(b, 3).multiply(jdpr.multiply(2).cos())) 
          .add(value(b, 4).multiply(jdpr.multiply(2).sin())) 
          .subtract(value(b, 5).multiply(jdpr.multiply(3).cos())) 
          .add(value(b, 6).multiply(jdpr.multiply(3).sin()));
  
    var cosSunZen = latRad.sin().multiply(delta.sin()) 
          .add(latRad.cos().multiply(ah.cos()).multiply(delta.cos()));
    var sunZen = cosSunZen.acos();
  
    // sun azimuth from south, turning west
    var sinSunAzSW = ah.sin().multiply(delta.cos()).divide(sunZen.sin());
    sinSunAzSW = sinSunAzSW.clamp(-1.0, 1.0);
  
    var cosSunAzSW = (latRad.cos().multiply(-1).multiply(delta.sin())
                    .add(latRad.sin().multiply(delta.cos()).multiply(ah.cos()))) 
                    .divide(sunZen.sin());
    var sunAzSW = sinSunAzSW.asin();
  
    sunAzSW = where(cosSunAzSW.lte(0), sunAzSW.multiply(-1).add(Math.PI), sunAzSW);
    sunAzSW = where(cosSunAzSW.gt(0).and(sinSunAzSW.lte(0)), sunAzSW.add(Math.PI).add(Math.PI), sunAzSW);
  
    var sunAz = sunAzSW.add(Math.PI);
     // # Keep within [0, 2pi] range
    sunAz = where(sunAz.gt(Math.PI*2), sunAz.subtract(Math.PI).subtract(Math.PI), sunAz);
  
    var footprint_polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon(footprint);
    sunAz = sunAz.clip(footprint_polygon);
    sunAz = sunAz.rename(['sunAz']);
    sunZen = sunZen.clip(footprint_polygon).rename(['sunZen']);
  
return [sunAz, sunZen]; 
}
// B.2 - Get View Azimuth angle from scene metadata
function ViewAzimuth(footprint){
    // Sub functions
    function x(point){return ee.Number(ee.List(point).get(0))}
    function y(point){return ee.Number(ee.List(point).get(1))}   

    var upperCenter = line_from_coords(footprint, 0, 3).centroid().coordinates(); // Upper left, Upper Right
    var lowerCenter = line_from_coords(footprint, 1, 2).centroid().coordinates(); // Lower left, Lower Right
    var slope = ((y(lowerCenter)).subtract(y(upperCenter))).divide((x(lowerCenter)).subtract(x(upperCenter)));
    var slopePerp = ee.Number(-1).divide(slope);
    var azimuthLeft = ee.Image(Math.PI).divide(2).subtract((slopePerp).atan());
return azimuthLeft.rename(['viewAz']);
}
// B.3 - Get View Zenith angle from scene metadata
function ViewZenith(footprint){
    var leftLine = line_from_coords(footprint, 0, 1);               // Upper left, Lower left
    var rightLine = line_from_coords(footprint, 3, 2);          // Upper Right, Lower Right
    var leftDistance = ee.FeatureCollection(leftLine).distance(1000000);        // Max Distance = 1 000 000
    var rightDistance = ee.FeatureCollection(rightLine).distance(1000000);      // Max Distance = 1 000 000
    var viewZenith = rightDistance.multiply(ee.Number(7.5 * 2)) // Max Satellite Zenith = 7.5
                                .divide(rightDistance.add(leftDistance)) 
                                .subtract(ee.Number(7.5))       // Max Satellite Zenith = 7.5
                                .clip(ee.Geometry.Polygon(footprint)) 
                                .rename(['viewZen']);
return viewZenith.multiply(Math.PI).divide(180);
}
// B.4 - Calculate kvol and kvol0 kernels
//(From Lucht et al. 2000 ; See also http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/9/12/1325/htm#sec3dot2-remotesensing-09-01325; https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425717302791
// Phase angle = cos(solar zenith) cos(view zenith) + sin(solar zenith) sin(view zenith) cos(relative azimuth)
function kvolCalc(sunAz, sunZen, viewAz, viewZen){ 
    // Calculate kvol
    var relative_azimuth = sunAz.subtract(viewAz).rename(['relAz']);
    var pa1 = viewZen.cos().multiply(sunZen.cos());
    var pa2 = viewZen.sin().multiply(sunZen.sin()).multiply(relative_azimuth.cos());
    var phase_angle1 = pa1.add(pa2);
    var phase_angle = phase_angle1.acos();
    var p1 = ee.Image(Math.PI).divide(2).subtract(phase_angle);
    var p2 = p1.multiply(phase_angle1);
    var p3 = p2.add(phase_angle.sin());
    var p4 = sunZen.cos().add(viewZen.cos());
    var p5 = ee.Image(Math.PI).divide(4);
    var kvol = p3.divide(p4).subtract(p5).rename(['kvol']);
    // Calculate kvol10
    var viewZen0 = ee.Image(0);
    var pa10 = viewZen0.cos().multiply(sunZen.cos());
    var pa20 = viewZen0.sin().multiply(sunZen.sin()).multiply(relative_azimuth.cos());
    var phase_angle10 = pa10.add(pa20);
    var phase_angle0 = phase_angle10.acos();
    var p10 = ee.Image(Math.PI).divide(2).subtract(phase_angle0);
    var p20 = p10.multiply(phase_angle10);
    var p30 = p20.add(phase_angle0.sin());
    var p40 = sunZen.cos().add(viewZen0.cos());
    var p50 = ee.Image(Math.PI).divide(4);
    var kvol0 = p30.divide(p40).subtract(p50).rename(['kvol0']);
return [kvol, kvol0];
}
// B.5 - Apply BRDF correction to all bands
function BRDFcorr(image, kvol, kvol0){
    var f_iso = 0;
    var f_geo = 0;
    var f_vol = 0;
    // Correct bands
    var blue = Correct_band(image, 'blue', kvol, kvol0, f_iso=0.0774, f_geo=0.0079, f_vol=0.0372);
    var green = Correct_band(image, 'green', kvol, kvol0, f_iso=0.1306, f_geo=0.0178, f_vol=0.0580);
    var red = Correct_band(image, 'red', kvol, kvol0, f_iso=0.1690, f_geo=0.0227, f_vol=0.0574);
    var nir = Correct_band(image, 'nir', kvol, kvol0, f_iso=0.3093, f_geo=0.0330, f_vol=0.1535);
    var swir1 = Correct_band(image, 'swir1', kvol, kvol0, f_iso=0.3430, f_geo=0.0453, f_vol=0.1154);   
    var swir2 = Correct_band(image, 'swir2', kvol, kvol0, f_iso=0.2658, f_geo=0.0387, f_vol=0.0639);
    // List non corrected bands
    var AllBands = image.bandNames();
    var nonCorrectBands = image.select(AllBands.removeAll(['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','swir2']));
return image.select([]).addBands([blue, green, red, nir, swir1, swir2]).addBands(nonCorrectBands);
}
// B.6 - Apply BRDF to a single band
function Correct_band(image, band_name, kvol, kvol0, f_iso, f_geo, f_vol){
    //"""fiso + fvol * kvol + fgeo * kgeo"""
    var iso = ee.Image(f_iso);
    var geo = ee.Image(f_geo);
    var vol = ee.Image(f_vol);
    var pred = vol.multiply(kvol).add(geo.multiply(kvol)).add(iso).rename(['pred']);
    var pred0 = vol.multiply(kvol0).add(geo.multiply(kvol0)).add(iso).rename(['pred0']);
    var cfac = pred0.divide(pred).rename(['cfac']);
    var corr = image.select(band_name).multiply(cfac).rename([band_name]);
    return corr;
}
// B.7 - Other helper functions                   
function line_from_coords(coordinates, fromIndex, toIndex){
return ee.Geometry.LineString(ee.List([coordinates.get(fromIndex),coordinates.get(toIndex)]));
}
function where(condition, trueValue, falseValue){
    var trueMasked = trueValue.mask(condition);
    var falseMasked = falseValue.mask(invertMask(condition));
return trueMasked.unmask(falseMasked);
}
function invertMask(mask){
return mask.multiply(-1).add(1);
}
function value(list,index){
return ee.Number(list.get(index));
}

// C.1 - Convert degrees to radians
function radians(img) {
  return img.toFloat().multiply(Math.PI).divide(180);
}

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3b8e3bf9384e807659e39b744938be5a
